# Background displayed as grid in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I was given a CSS file to look at in order to solve a few problems with it. The background for one of the sections is styled as such:

```
#rt-showcase {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
}
```

and looks as expected in Firefox, it is a white background. However, when the page is displayed in Chrome the background is displayed as a grid. Does anyone know why this might occur, and what the grid means? Is it possibly a transparency issue?

Comment: can you make a fiddle : http://www.jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Look fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/S2rSn/. Probably something else going on so you need to show more code

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do you expect.
If you just want a white background in all browsers just use:

```
#rt-showcase {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: When I look at this page with the Chrome developer tools that is what it shows for that line.

Comment: But what is written in the CSS file?